# Alertdialog is not showing when button is clicked in onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android

How do I make the alert dialog show up when I click a button in layout? The code below works if the button is from the menu but I need it to function from a layout button.I tried replacing `case R.id.action_add_task` with `case R.id.button`(button being the name of the layout button) but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Add something");
            builder.setMessage("What do you nat to do?");
            final EditText inputField = new EditText(getActivity());
            builder.setView(inputField);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //Get user input
                    String inputTask = inputField.getText().toString();

                    //Get DBHelper to write to database
                    TaskDBHelper helper = new TaskDBHelper(getActivity());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

                    //Put in the values within a ContentValues.
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.clear();
                    values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK, inputTask);

                    //Insert the values into the Table for Tasks
                    db.insertWithOnConflict(
                            TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                            null,
                            values,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

                    //Query database again to get updated data
                    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK},
                            null, null, null, null, null);

                    //Swap old data with new data for display
                    mTaskAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            builder.create().show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: If you mean a button that's on your activity, this won't work. `onOptionsItemSelected` is only for buttons on the option menu.

Comment: setOnClickListener on button instead adding your logic to onOptionItemSelected

Comment: is it inside activity or fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something on Button click, use:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Do something on click
     }
})
```

This will work for any Button in your activity (does not work for action bar icons and overflow menu items)

Answer (score 0):

Declare Button in XML like this

`<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="handleButton"
            android:text="Button" />`

In the Java class handle the click by creating a method for the button using the onClick attribute declared in Xml

```
`public void handleButton(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Your title here");
    dialog.setMessage("Message body");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
    dialog.show();             
    return ;
}
```